# What's the logical name for Android's native GPS interface?

Tags: hardware, gps, kernel, development, device-name

I'm trying to identify and locate the `/dev/` pseudo-file that corresponds to the onboard, hardware GPS devices; installed in most modern Android smartphones, and tablets. I know that it probably varies sometimes, but the vast majority more than likely use a standard, logical name.

If you have no idea what I'm talking about; some examples of common, logical names for other kinds of hardware that you might recognize, are:

`tty0`, `mouse0`, `event0`, `eth0`, `wlan0`, `sr0`, `video0`, `media0`, `bus0`, `usb0` `gps0`, `disk0`, `sda1`, `sdb2`, `sdc3`, and so on.

Most of these live inside `/dev/`, and it's subdirectories; such as `/dev/input/`.